# Create multiple files and name them from command line

Tags: linux, bash, xargs

I need to create 300 blank files and put them in a folder on my server then name them from a list in a txt file, I have SSH access, so is it possible to do this using command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `xargs` for this:

`xargs -a file_list.txt touch`

This supplies each line of the text file as the parameter to `touch`. There's no point in creating the files first, might as well just create the outright with the correct name from your text file.

If you wish to output to an arbitrary directory, eg `PATH` then try:

`cat file_list.txt | xargs -I % touch PATH/%`

Answer (score 2):

For simple way to do it try.

```
touch $(cat filename.txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read filename; do
  touch $filename
done < filename.txt
```

This will iterate over each line of filename.txt and create empty file with name in the current line.

Comment: how would I specify the folder to create the files?

Comment: @user1860410: change the `touch $filename` to `touch PATH/$filename` where PATH is an abolute or relative path to the folder.